# Appending Header Record in Flat file SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssis-2008, script-task

I have created an *SSIS* package which goes from **OLEDB Source** to **Flat File Destination**.

Now what I want to do is append an extra rows before and after the records.

> I already have Column Header in Flat File.

Appending an extra row at the end can be achieved by **ScriptTask**. But is there any way, I can append the first rows in flat file. Is there any way from which we can select the where that row needs to be append.

> Even the first and last rows that needs to be appended does not match the column that are in that File

Lets say The file is generated having 40 columns in it. And that row which needs to appended has only 4 columns and that too are different.

Can anyone help me out with this?

Comment: Can anyone share the script task code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also append the first row with a script task.  It's a simple matter of programming.

Comment: Well, I got that! That was simple. Thank you!!

Comment: @KinchitDalwani if this answer solved your issue you have to [accept it](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour)